# Is there anyway use Google's API to convert Google Slide to SVG?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I need convert a Slide to SVGs via Google's API, and I found that Google Slide support download as SVG in their FE.
and I'm trying use the [export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/export) API to convert that and meet follow response:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdkzS.png)
Does anyone know of any API that can meet the above requirements? I haven't found a similar API in the development documentation.